# Understanding Ruby - undefined local variable

Tags: ruby, variables

I've been playing around with Ruby and have come across this weird behavior. Could anyone please tell me why this is happening?

if I run:

```
def my_fn
  if false then
    a = {:a=>10, :b=>20}
  end
  puts a.class
  a || {}
end
```

and print the result the code compiles successfully and returns {}.
But if I change the code to:

```
def my_fn
  puts a.class
  a || {}
end
```

it doesn't return {} but throws an Error. `"'my_fn': undefined local variable or method 'a' for main:Object (NameError)"`

Shouldn't a just be nil and not cause an error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because - [*The local variable is created when the parser encounters the assignment, not when the assignment occurs*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods).

In the first code parser sees the line `a = {:a=>10, :b=>20}`, so a variable created, but no assignment happened. Thus `a` is `nil`. [As per the all known facts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[ruby]+%22||%22) `a || {}` returns `{}`.

In the second code there parser didn't see any assignment happened with `a`, so `a` has not been created as a local variable nor you create a method named as `a`. Thus when you tried to use `a`, got a valid error as you reported, which is *undefined local variable or method 'a'*.

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you know any advantages of using this approach? It doesn't seem very intuitive to me.

Comment: @chibi03 I linked the documentation also, please go through that, plenty of knowledge there.